# How can I use tokens for Addressfield values without using Addressfield_tokens?

Tags: 7, tokens, path-aliases, entities

I would like to use the Town/ City field as a token for Pathauto. I thought the Addressfield_tokens module was perfect for this, but Entity Tokens breaks Pathauto's patterns control panel; the issue seems to be common and unresolved.

I'm wondering what other options I might have for extracting the Town/ City value from Addressfield and using it as a token in a Pathauto pattern?

Answer (score 0):

If Pathauto uses the core Token system, then you can follow along in [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1188778) where we'll be adding token support directly to Address Field asap.